# Safe await on function in another process

Tags: c++11, multiprocessing, gunicorn, python-asyncio, locust

**TL;DR**

How to safely `await` on function execution (takes `str` and `int` as arguments and doesn't require any other context) in a separate process?

**Long story**

I have `aiohtto.web` web API that uses `Boost.Python` wrapper for `C++` extension, run under `gunicorn` (and I plan to deploy it on Heroku), tested by `locust`.

About extension: it have just one function that does non-blocking operation - takes one string (and one integer for timeout management), does some calculations with it and returns a new string. And for every input string, it is only one possible output (except timeout, but in that case, `C++` exception must be raised and translated by Boost.Python to a Python-compatible one).

In short, a handler for specific URL executes the code below:

```
res = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, func, *args)
```

where `executor` is the `ProcessPoolExecutor` instance, and `func` -function from C++ extension module. (in the real project, this code is in the coroutine method of the class, and `func` - it's `classmethod` that only executes `C++` function and returns the result)

**Error catching**

When a new request arrives, I extract it's POST data by `request.post()` and then storing it's data to the instance of the custom class named `Call` (because I have no idea how to name it in another way). So that `call` object contains all input data (string), request receiving time and unique `id` that comes with the request.

Then it proceeds to class named `Handler` (not the `aiohttp` request handler), that passes it's input to another class' method with `loop.run_in_executor` inside. But `Handler` has a logging system that works like a middleware - reads id and receiving time of every incoming `call` object and logging it with a message that tells you either it just starting to execute, successfully executed or get in trouble. Also, `Handler` have `try/except` and stores all errors inside the `call` object, so that logging middleware knows what error occurred, or what output extension had returned

**Testing**

I have the unit test that just creates 256 coroutines with this code inside and executor that have 256 workers and it works well.

But when testing with Locust here comes a problem. I use 4 Gunicorn workers and 4 executor workers for this kind of testing. At some time application just starts to return wrong output.

My Locust's `TaskSet` is configured to log every fault response with all available information: output string, error string, input string (that was returned by the application too), id. All simulated requests are the same, but `id` is unique for every.

The situation is better when setting Gunicorn's `max_requests` option to `100` requests, but failures still come.

Interesting thing is, that sometimes I can trigger "wrong output" period by simply stopping and starting Locust's test.

I need a 100% guarantee that my web API works as I expect.

**UPDATE & solution**

Just asked my teammate to review the C++ code - the problem was in **global variables**. In some way, it wasn't a problem for 256 parallel coroutines, but for Gunicorn was.

Comment: I don't know why this is tagged [tag:locust]. Basically it sounds like your web service doesn't scale?

Comment: @enderland scalabling isn't so necneccesary getting expected output from the web API. I have added note about Locust's test in the last edit.

Comment: Did you log results of run_in_executor to be sure problem is C-code related? It's not clear what "wrong output" app returns. May be server just can't handle this amount of parallel requests regardless of executor stuff.

Comment: @GerasimovMikhail C++ code do calculations, so for example, if it does arithmetic calculations than for '2 + 2' input string it must return '4' every. Locust test do something like sending hundreds of requests with '2 + 2', so I expect that every response must be '4', but it doesn't. I have updated the question with information about logging and kinda solution. Should I rename the question?